# SQL Server 2012 - Convert(varchar,'2018-12-16 17:33:29',105) + ' ' Convert(varchar,'2018-12-16 17:33:29',108) is not showing correct data

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-conversion, getdate

I have a `datetime` datatype column with the data format '16-12-2018 17:33:29' (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss). So if I get input data as 2018-12-16 17:33:29, the data needs to be converted into '16-12-2018 17:33:29'.

This is the datatype conversion I have been trying,

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2018-12-16 17:33:29', 105) + ' ' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2018-12-16 17:33:29', 108)
```

Output is: `2018-12-16 2018-12-16`

But if I use `Getdate()` instead of hardcoded value I'm getting the expected data format:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) + ' '  + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Output is: `16-12-2018 17:36:18`

My question is, why the same datatype conversion query is working if we use `getdate()` but not in hardcoded values?

[image]

Comment: If the column has a datetime datatype, then it does NOT have a particular format

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @marc_s, I have modified the question as well as tried the query but getting same result in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query has a date value as second parameter. Your first query has just a string there.
The fact that that string looks like a date is not important as far as SQL is concerned.

**Edit**. 
When your column has a datetime type, then use datetime values to transport data. Try and keep away from strings as often as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So If I want to check my query using a hardcoded value, how could I check? `SELECT Convert(varchar(10),'2018-12-16 17:33:29',105) + ' ' +Convert(varchar(10),'2018-12-16 17:33:29',108)`

Comment: I understand your point. So since it is string value, whatever I'm giving it is showing the 10 characters as output. Am I right?

Comment: Conversion of varchar to varchar shouldn't do anything. Do not convert to varchar, but to datetime. That should help.